# postgreSQL inicia pero no carga pantalla principal

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

instalé postgreSQL en mi PC con windows 10 para un curso que estoy haciendo. Estuve practicando varias horas sin problemas pero de repente se tildó y me ví obligado a finalizar el proceso de la app con el administrador de tareas. Cuando lo quiero volver a abrir la página de inicio no responde y no carga como debería. A continuación adjunto una foto:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, cada vez que lo abro queda en esa pantalla y ninguno de los botones funciona. Intenté desinstalando e instalando varias veces, incluso volviendo a descargar el installer pero siempre aparece el mismo bug. Alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo??